# mPDF terminating displaying php code

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I am working with mPDF, I can't handle how to display php variable and generate&download PDF file.
Example :

```
$a = '<head><body>Example</body></head>';
echo $a;
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<head><body>Example</body></head>');
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

This code only downloading pdf generated from ->WriteHTML but not displaying code above. I would display code and download pdf.
Thx for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push a download and have it preceeded by HTML in one response.

You can work around this by outputting the HTML and have it include an IFRAME which has a src attribute of the url with the actual download.

dl_html.php:

```
<?php
$a = '<head><body>Example<iframe style="display:none;" src="dl_pdf.php"></iframe></body></head>';
echo $a;
```

dl_pdf.php:

```
 <?php
    include('mpdf.php');//or similar
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<head><body>Example</body></head>');
    $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Can you write some simple example?